# get x y location of a textbox inside scrollview

Tags: ios

The layout of my UIViewController is :

Layer 1:UIView  (height is 568)
Layer 2:UIScrollView (height is 2000)
Layer 3:UIView (height is 2000)

i have lot of textfield inside this layer 3 UIView, i would like to know the current x y showing on layer1 UIView (not the layer 3 UIView original x y)

should i use convertPoint ? I got invalid results

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {


    CGPoint newPoint = [textField convertPoint:textField.frame.origin fromView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"%f",textField.frame.origin.y);
    NSLog(@"%f", newPoint.y);

}
```

Comment: just use CGFloat for getting textField.frame.origin.x and y

Comment: if the textField is at the bottom of the UIView, the textField.frame.origin.y will be 1800 for example. so this is not the current y location. i want to know the current Y location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create IBOutlet for your Layer 1 view and Layer 3 view.

in your ViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *superView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *subView;
```

in your ViewController.m

```
CGPoint originInSuperview = [self.superView convertPoint:textField.frame.origin fromView:self.subView];
```

Then you will have the SuperView x y location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use superview means a view which holds the another view over it. It manages subviews. Subviews means the views which are holding/added over a 'View'.

Lets Say. you have a SuperView UIview which has a subview UIScrollView and which has another subview UIview over it.

[Might be it helps you.  The event-handling methods: OnTouch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW24)

Comment: yes i think the layer 1 UIView is the superview as you mentioned. so how can i implement ?

Comment: Use event-handling methods: as i attached link

Comment: sorry chandan, i am using such technique to build, my questions is i want to know the x and y on screen when use scroll up the textField from the scrollView. because some of the textField is very bottom, the original x and y is useless in this case. i need the on screen x and y of the textField.

Comment: CGPoint originInSuperview = [self.superView convertPoint:textField.frame.origin fromView:self.subView]; i found this works. but i have to make those 2 view IBOutlet first.

Answer (score 0):

```
UITextField *myTextField;
```

Get textFiled origin x and Y

```
myTextField.frame.origin.x;
myTextField.frame.origin.y;
```

Get Minmum(origin) and maximum (end) and mid point of textFiled

```
CGRectGetMinX(myTextField.frame);
CGRectGetMaxX(myTextField.frame);
CGRectGetMinY(myTextField.frame);
CGRectGetMaxY(myTextField.frame);
CGRectGetMidX(myTextField.frame);
CGRectGetMidY(myTextField.frame);
```